# NextAuth : Unable to query User model, when using NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth for my Nextjs/ MongoDB application. I am getting an error when i try to query the User record in an Api file.

```
import Users from '../../../model/user';

let userId = query.id;
const userData = await Users.findOne({_id:userId});
console.log('userData ',userData);
```

I am getting the below error :

```
error :  _model_user__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.findOne is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `query`? I think you need `req.query.id`, because you have `req` and `res` in API requests and responses
2. You need to transform your `userId` to `ObjectId`

   ```
   import Users from '../../../model/user';
   import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

    ...your method of handler, eg get, post, delete etc

   //if you have name [id].tsx, for [pid].tsx you need req.query.pid
   let userId = req.query.id;

   //you need to transform only if you are searching by _id field
   const userData = await Users.findOne({"_id": ObjectId(userId)});
   if (userData.?_id){
    res.status(200).json(userData)
   }
   else{
    res.status(500).json('User data not found')
   }
   ```